# Excel "Like ... Then" Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have some value like Laptop xx, Laptop yy and I want to search "Laptop" word

I tried this :

```
If MyInput Like "* Cells(x, 3).Value *" Then

do this
```

MyInput Value is "Laptop"

Cells(x,3).Value is "Laptop xx" and "Laptop yy"

the result should write this 2 item to my blank sheet

But the result nothing changed.

I've read about hardcoding but I need to pass value here so TIA and excuse me for bad English

Comment: When you put the "quotes around text" makes it taken literally.  So it's not the value that MyInput is compared to, it's the literal text inside the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Like as you are in your example you should be using it like this:

```
If MyInput Like "*" & Cells(x, 3).Value & "*" Then

do this
```

Comment: You may have `MyInput` and `Cells(x, 3).Value` backwards for the OP's intentions; e.g. Is MyInput (*Laptop*) within Cells(x, 3).Value (*Laptop xx*)?

Comment: Okay after I combined both of your answer, I got the result that I want :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use something like the INSTR function, I've not tested this but and IF statement like this may work for you, assuming x is a parameter you're calculating?

```
IF InStr(Cells(x, 3).Value, MyInput) = True Then
     ...
End if
```

Comment: I find that a direct literal comparison to *True* often results in a false negative; e.g. `InStr` returning *5* does not strictly equal *True* (in VBA *-1*). The following works well for me: `If CBool(InStr(Cells(x, 3).Value, MyInput, vbTextCompare)) Then`.

Comment: `IF InStr(1, MyInput, Cells(x, 3).Value, MyInput, vbTextCompare) > 0 then` and don't forget that  The start argument is required if compare is specified, see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811%28v=office.15%29.aspx)